# magnetic intensity of cylinder sheet of charge having surface charge density K

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Here is the problem I have

[image]

by using

[image]

$$a_z\times R = (0,0,1) \times (\rho-1.2,0,-z) = (\rho -1.2)a_\phi $$

$$H=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2.4(\rho-1.2)d\phi dz}{4\pi ((\rho-1.2)^2+z^2)^{3/2}} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2.4(\rho-1.2)dz}{2 ((\rho-1.2)^2+z^2)^{3/2}}=1.2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(\rho-1.2)dz}{((\rho-1.2)^2+z^2)^{3/2}}$$

by using wolfram alpha, the result is $\frac{12}{5\rho-6}a_\phi$ However the result of my textbook is

[image]

What is the mistake I did here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the key problem is that you are conducting your integration over the wrong surface.

The problem is, you have an infinitely extending sheet of charge on the surface $\rho=1.2$. Based on this, as you seem to have done, we work in cylindrical coordinates and consider a plane of constant $z$.

Taking your expression:

[image: Magnetic Field Strength Equation]

and converting it into cylindrical coordinates $(a_\rho,a_\theta,a_z)$:

$$
\textbf{H} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_S{\frac{\textbf{K}\times \textbf{a}_\rho}{R ^2}\rho d\rho d\phi}
$$

(where we have taken constants outside the integration) we see the appropriate surface element. The final step as I see it is to realise that **K** (which is in the $\textbf{a}_z$ direction) should be considered a function of $\rho$, but the initial conditions given in the question will allow you to change the surface integral into an integral around a loop.

The other error was in your evaluation of the cross product, as rather than evaluating $K\times a_\rho$ (substituing $\rho$ for R for consistency), where $a_\rho$ is the radial unit vector, you did $a_z\times R$ where your vector R seems to point from the surface of the plane to an infinite line at radius $\rho$.

So to summarise, try the problem again but:

Evaluate the cross product using the current per unit length (**K**) and radial unit vectors correctly.

Conduct the surface integral over the circular plane of constant z and radius $\rho$, remembering that R is a constant (The distance from the centre of the circle to your point of evaluation, e.g. $\rho$) and that **K** only has a value when $\rho=1.2$.

Bump if you still have problems.

As a P.S.,I approached this problem from the integral form of Ampere's Law, as it allowed me to separate the point of evaluation and the location of current density (**J**.

$$
\int{\textbf{H}\,d\textbf{l}}=\int{\textbf{J}\,d\textbf{S}}
$$